# Terraform module throws `Error: Insufficient attribute blocks`

Tags: terraform

Having a weird issue where I'm getting `Error: Insufficient attribute blocks` when running my TF code...

dynamodb module

```
locals {
  my_name = "${var.prefix}-${var.env}-${var.name}"
  my_env  = "${var.prefix}-${var.env}"
}

resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "dynamodb-instance" {
  name           = "${local.my_name}"
  read_capacity  = 5
  write_capacity = 5
  hash_key       = "${var.hash_key_name}"
  attribute      ["${var.attributes_list}"]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${local.my_name}"
    Environment = "${local.my_env}"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}

variable "prefix" {}
variable "env" {}
variable "name" {}
variable "hash_key_name" {}

variable "attributes_list" {
  type = "list"
}
```

dynamodb-tables module

```
# The session dynamodb table.
module "dynamodb-session" {
  source        = "../dynamodb"
  prefix        = "${var.prefix}"
  env           = "${var.env}"
  name          = "session"
  hash_key_name = "token"

  attributes_list = [
    {
      name = "token"
      type = "S"
    },
  ]
}

# The users dynamodb table.
# NOTE: I should have named it "user" for consistency.
module "dynamodb-users" {
  source        = "../dynamodb"
  prefix        = "${var.prefix}"
  env           = "${var.env}"
  name          = "users"
  hash_key_name = "email"

  attributes_list = [
    {
      name = "email"
      type = "S"
    },
  ]
}

# The product-group dynamodb table.
module "dynamodb-product-group" {
  source        = "../dynamodb"
  prefix        = "${var.prefix}"
  env           = "${var.env}"
  name          = "product-group"
  hash_key_name = "pgid"

  attributes_list = [
    {
      name = "pgid"
      type = "S"
    },
  ]
}

# The product dynamodb table is a bit different because of secondary index.
# Let's create it directly here.
resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "product-dynamodb-instance" {
  name           = "${var.prefix}-${var.env}-product"
  read_capacity  = 5
  write_capacity = 5
  hash_key       = "pid"
  range_key      = "pgid"

  global_secondary_index {
    name               = "PGIndex"
    hash_key           = "pgid"
    range_key          = "pid"
    write_capacity     = 5
    read_capacity      = 5
    projection_type    = "INCLUDE"
    non_key_attributes = ["price", "title"]
  }

  // attribute [[
  //   {
  //     name = "pid"
  //     type = "S"
  //   },
  //   {
  //     name = "pgid"
  //     type = "S"
  //   },
  // ]]

  tags = {
    Name        = "${var.prefix}-${var.env}-product"
    Environment = "${var.prefix}-${var.env}"
    Terraform   = "true"
  }
}


variable "prefix" {}
variable "env" {}
variable "region" {}
```

Not sure whats going on?

Comment: Have you forgotten a `=` sign in the line `attribute      ["${var.attributes_list}"]`?

Comment: That gives the error ```Error: Unsupported argument

  on ../../modules/dynamodb-tables/dynamodb-tables.tf line 69, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "product-dynamodb-instance":
  69:   attribute = [```

Comment: Full code base is here, https://github.com/Gabelbombe/terraform-eks

Comment: This is actually taking advantage of missed validation checks in versions of terraform <0.12 (and potentially some newer versions of 0.11) The 0.12 way to do this is with dynamic blocks. You may still be able to get this to work though, I'd try `attribute      = "${var.attributes_list}"` without the enclosing brackets

Comment: Check out cloud posse's dynamodb module for an example how to do this in 0.12 https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-dynamodb/blob/master/main.tf#L81